# X axis label is not displayed fully in recharts

Tags: recharts

As you can see here in the screenshoot, at the bottom center(x axis), the label `Quiz/Exam` is cropped.
I increased the height for the Line Chart, but it does only increase the graph size.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same problem and fixed it by adding a [margin](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/LineChart#margin) to the chart, eg;

```
<LineChart
  <LineChart
    margin={{
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 15
    }}
...
>
```

Comment: Yes margin fixed the issue.